# Reversing the order of nested IObservables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'd like to swap the ordering of a pair of nested `IObservables`, with a couple of constraints on the way in which it occurs.

As a concrete (albeit a bit contrived) example, suppose there's a game server hosting successive online multiplayer games. Players can join in at any time and perform actions within each game. The following classes have working implementations which provide a read-only view of actions performed by players during successive games:

```
class GameServer
{
  public IObservable<Game> Games { get { ... } }
}

class Game
{
  public int GameId { get { ... } }
  public IObservable<GamePlayer> Players { get { ... } }
}

class GamePlayer
{
  public int PlayerId { get { ... } }
  public IObservable<PlayerAction> PlayerActions { get { ... } }
}
```

Within these classes, there is a nested observable `IObservable<IObservable<IObservable<PlayerAction>>>`. This is giving information of the form: `There are a series of games. Within each game a series of players joined. Each player performed a number of actions in the game`.

What I'd like to do is to rearrange this data so it instead gives this information: `There are a number of players. Since each player joined, a series of games have been played. Within each game, the player performed a number of actions.` This would look like an implementation of the following method:

```
IObservable<Player> Players { get; }
```

Using the following classes:

```
class Player
{
  public Player(int playerId, IObservable<PlayerGame> games)
  {
    PlayerId = playerId;
    Games = games;
  }

  public int PlayerId { get; private set; }
  public IObservable<PlayerGame> Games { get; private set; }
}

class PlayerGame
{
  public PlayerGame(int gameId, IObservable<PlayerAction> gameActions)
  {
    GameId = gameId;
    GameActions = gameActions;
  }

  public int GameId { get; private set; }
  public IObservable<PlayerAction> GameActions { get; private set; }
}
```

Rather than providing a sequence of games and showing for each one what each player does, this would provide a sequence of players and show for each their involvement in successive games.

**And one extra requirement**: Once a player has joined, their actions for every successive game should be shown, regardless of whether they did anything during that game (i.e. if a Player does nothing during a Game, the `Player` should still push a new `PlayerGame` when the game starts, even if its `GameActions` never pushes a value).

**How would I go about implementing `Players` using `GameServer.Games` as the source of the relevant data?**

*(In response to DaveSexton's comments: what the IDs stand for, where the data comes from and what framework or environment the program works in isn't important. All the required data is present in the `GameServer`, `Game` and `GamePlayer` classes. I just don't know how to reshuffle it into the `Player` form.)*

### An almost-working solution

To give a better idea of the sort of thing I'm aiming for, here's a solution that almost works. The only problem with it is that if a new game starts and `GameServer.Games` pushes a new `Game`, `Player.Games` doesn't correspondingly push a new `PlayerGame` for each existing player (which I'd like it to).

```
Players = gameServer.Games
  .Select(g => g.Players.Select(p => new { g.GameId, p.PlayerId, p.PlayerActions }))
  .Switch()
  .GroupBy(t => t.PlayerId)
  .Select(
    group => 
    new Player(group.Key, group.Select(t => new PlayerGame(t.GameId, t.PlayerActions))));
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: @DaveSexton Added an actual question to the end - how would I implement `Players` using `GameServer.Games` as the data source?

Comment: It can't be done based on the types provided (and I'm not willing to assume anything about your types that you've elided). `Games` is a sequence of `Game`, which contains a sequence of `GamePlayer`, yet `Players` is a sequence of `Player`, which contains a sequence of `PlayerGame`. `GamePlayer` and `PlayerGame` are totally different types.

Comment: I think I see what you mean - `Player` and `PlayerGame` were just simple wrapper classes around their properties. Maybe it'll make what I'm asking clearer if I change the second set of classes to interfaces.

Comment: Based on the information provided, the answer is no. The proposed `Player` type and its related types are totally different types compared to the `Game` type and its related types. You haven't described any way to convert between them. How can you get a list of `Player` from a list of `GamePlayer`? The latter only provides a `PlayerId` property, not a property of type `Player`.

Comment: @DaveSexton Sorry, I think I misunderstood what you were saying. I have control over the Player and PlayerGame classes, so really what I'm asking for is that they implement a particular interface.

Comment: Changing the classes to interfaces makes no difference.

Comment: @DaveSexton Given your comment that it can't be done without making assumptions about the types, I changed them to interfaces to indicate that they don't have a defined implementation yet and they can be implemented any way that makes sense with the solution.

Comment: I've answered your question in terms of Rx: Use `SelectMany`. Nobody's going to implement your types for you, especially without knowing anything about your service, environment, constraints, etc. But even if you specified them, your question is still way too broad for StackOverflow, IMHO.

Comment: I'm not asking for my types to be implemented for me, and the surrounding environment shouldn't be important - the data's all present in the `Game` classes, but I can't figure out how to regroup it into the `Person` classes. I've added an example solution which almost works, aside from the constraint that all `Player` classes should push a `PlayerGame` when the `GameServer` pushes a new `Game`.

Comment: It still seems like you're missing information. I stand by my answer; you need to implement a hypothetical `CreatePlayer` method, as in my `SelectMany` query. For example, what is the `Player` class's `IObservable<PlayerGame> Games` property supposed to contain? Just a single game or possibly more than one game? I assume the latter, because the former doesn't make much sense. However, your "almost working" solution only ever creates `Player` objects for a single `Game`. It *does not* create a one-to-many association, if that's what you're assuming. And it's *hot*, so you can miss it!

Comment: I've updated my answer with what seems to be a possible solution for you, based on the new information that you've provided. I've expanded on my original `SelectMany` query by incorporating `Publish`, although you might not need it depending on whether `Games` is *hot* already, and implemented `CreatePlayer` as an in-line projection similar to how you've shown in your example query.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer** based on new information and example query provided by OP.

```
Players  = Games.Publish(publishedGames => 
             from game in publishedGames
             from player in game.Players
             select new Player(
               player.PlayerId, 
               (from game2 in publishedGames
                from player2 in game2.Players
                where player2.PlayerId == player.PlayerId
                select new PlayerGame(game2.GameId, player2.PlayerActions))
                .StartWith(new PlayerGame(game.GameId, player.PlayerActions))))
           .Distinct(player => player.PlayerId)
```

This is really just a `SelectMany` query at heart. For each `Game`, for each `GamePlayer`, it projects a new `Player`.

The original problem was how to create a new `Player` from a `GamePlayer`. What you've shown in your example query is that you simply want to convert `PlayerGame` objects from `Game` objects; therefore, I've just used an inner query that filters for games that have the player's ID. That's it.

`Publish` is only used in case `Games` is *cold*. If it's *hot*, then you don't need `Publish`.

I added `Distinct` because without it, whenever a `Game` is observed with players that have already been observed, those players would have been observed again.

Comment: It's the `IPlayerGame.GameActions` that's causing the main issue - the IDs were there to clarify where the data was moving around to. In the first set of classes, `PlayerActions` are the actions taken by the `GamePlayer` in the parent `Game`. In the second set, `GameActions` needs to be the actions taken in a `PlayerGame` by the parent `Player` (even if the `Player` doesn't perform any actions - it should be an empty sequence in this case).

Comment: Nobody can answer how you should implement `CreatePlayer` using the types that you've provided. It seems like that's your question, or at least that it's a prerequisite. I don't know anything about the environment in which your application runs, whether `PlayerId` refers to a database or an actor, etc. Frankly, it doesn't matter. Even if you provided that information your question is just way too broad.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I should have mentioned that the observables in question are all hot.

Comment: That's probably the best you're going to get without knowing more about your observable sources and the environment.

Comment: Hey Dave glad to have found you once again, you gave me superb help a few years back on Reactive Extensions, Thanks for that!

Comment: @PhilipC Note that I fixed a bug in my query. A reference to `player` should have been `player2` instead. Now subsequent games contain the player's actions for that game, not the first game.